# Windows SIM is failing to open a .wim with a System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: windows-10-v1809, wim

I'm trying to validate my Answer file using Windows System Image Manager. To do this, I need to open the Install.wim off of the .iso provided by my vendor, however when I try to open both the x64 and x86 versions of the install.wim, I get the same error. I've included the error dialog and the text from the log file below.

> **Windows System Image Manager**
>
> ---
>
> Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog. 
>   For troubleshooting assistance, see the topic:
>   'Windows System Image Manager Technical Reference'
>   in the Windows ADK User's Guide.
>
> Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformImplementation,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   or one of its dependencies. 
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

[<sup>[Click to see an image of Windows System Image Manager Error Dialog]</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrn7X.png)

```
14:40 : 
14:40 : Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog. For troubleshooting assistance, see the topic: 'Windows System Image Manager Technical Reference' in the Windows ADK User's Guide.
14:40 : 
14:40 : System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformImplementation, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformImplementation, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.Cpi.CreateOfflineImageInstance(OfflineImageInfo imageInfo)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.OfflineImageCatalog.Serialize(OfflineImageInfo imageInfo)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.OfflineImageInfo.CreateCatalog()
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.CatalogCreatorImpl.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.ICatalogCreator.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.CatalogGenerator.CreateCat(ProgressDialog pd, Object o)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: _`An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`_ This is indicative of a problem with the WIM file.  Are you certain it was a WIM file and not an ESD file?  If it was the latter, convert it to WIM with `DISM`.  Otherwise, verify the images contained within the WIM: `DISM /get-wiminfo /wimfile:z:\install.wim` (for index info, add `/index:<#>`).  Outside of that, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot, as it's an issue with the image, other than using a different image if unable to determine what the issue is with the image.

Comment: The extension on the install.wim is ".wim" can an esd file have a .wim extension? I've also already used the install.wim to install a base image on a device, and it is working there.

Comment: No, an ESD file is a different image format that utilizes a compression algorithm that's ~33% more efficient than WIM's _(ESD from Windows 10 forward is only allowed on WIMboot and one other type of image)_.  IIRC from when I had a similar issue a few years back, the `install.wim` is missing a file from it's Windows directory.  This was a common issue with most of the Windows 8 & 8.1 images, but I can't recall what file it was that needed to be added.

Comment: Any chance you remember how you figured out the missing file? I can go off on the google hunt myself, but if you have any suggestions for search starting points, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't... I looked through my bookmarks before posting my previous reply, as I was hoping I had bookmarked it, but it appears I either did not, or I deleted it once I upgraded to Windows 10 years ago.

Comment: That's okay, I appreciate the clue!

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` actually is totally unrelated to the WIM file. The “image” refers to a DLL the application is trying to load. It means the installation of SIM or Windows itself is somehow corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have just hit this error.

I was still on Windows 10 1809, but installed the Windows 10 1903 ADK.

Once I removed the 1903 ADK then installed 1809's ADK, install.wim was successfully cataloged.

Comment: Also found I needed to install the ADK on a 32-bit version of Windows 10 if I want to configure a 32-bit target installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i didn't downgrade version yet Microsoft has issued patch for   `imagecat.exe & imgmgr.exe` .. just download and replace those two components fixed the issue. you can download those patch from here.

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2095334

download and extract

[image]

and replace the files located under below location.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\WSIM
```

files need be replaced are

```
imagecat.exe

imgmgr.exe
```

original source: 
https://www.manishbangia.com/troubleshooting-adk-1903-unable-to-generate-a-catalog/