# Does Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 have the Embedded Features of Windows 10 IOT Enterprise LTSC 2019?

Tags: iot, windows-10-1809

I've found information that implies IOT Enterprise is binary identical to regular Enterprise, but I'm having some trouble with my answer file that tries to call on Embedded features.

Specifically, I'm getting an error in the logs that it can't find a namespace for Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-EmbeddedLogon and Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-ShellLauncher. I've included what I believe is the relevant section of the logs below.

```
2019-04-29 10:02:03, Warning                      [setup.exe] SMI data results dump: Source = Name: Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-ShellLauncher, Language: neutral, ProcessorArchitecture: amd64, PublicKeyToken: 31bf3856ad364e35, VersionScope: NonSxS
2019-04-29 10:02:03, Warning                      [setup.exe] SMI data results dump: Description = Unable to find a component matching the given namespace.
2019-04-29 10:02:03, Warning                      [setup.exe] SMI data results dump: Source = Name: Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-EmbeddedLogon, Language: neutral, ProcessorArchitecture: amd64, PublicKeyToken: 31bf3856ad364e35, VersionScope: nonSxS
2019-04-29 10:02:03, Warning                      [setup.exe] SMI data results dump: Description = Unable to find a component matching the given namespace.
```

The XML in my answer file is as follows:

```
<settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ComputerName>*</ComputerName>
        <Display>
            <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
            <DPI>96</DPI>
            <HorizontalResolution>768</HorizontalResolution>
            <RefreshRate>60</RefreshRate>
            <VerticalResolution>1024</VerticalResolution>
        </Display>
        <Themes>
            <ThemeName>Viper Theme</ThemeName>
            <DesktopBackground>%WINDIR%\Web\Wallpaper\SpectrumMedicalBackground.jpg</DesktopBackground>
        </Themes>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-EmbeddedLogon" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <AnimationDisabled>1</AnimationDisabled>
        <HideAutoLogonUI>1</HideAutoLogonUI>
        <NoLockScreen>1</NoLockScreen>
        <UIVerbosityLevel>1</UIVerbosityLevel>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-ShellLauncher" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Shell>C:\Launcher.exe</Shell>
        <DefaultReturnCodeAction>3</DefaultReturnCodeAction>
    </component>
</settings>
```

UPDATE:
I found a program called "ShellLauncherConfig.exe" in a directory that matched the "Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-ShellLauncher" name and tried to run it from powershell. I got an error that the executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Comment: Are you supplying a source to the feature in question?  The error you are getting is indicating the source, you are using to enable the Windows Features in question, does not include those features.  In other words, the data required to enable the feature, does not exist on your system currently.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm entirely self taught regarding image development, and for windows 10 I taught myself by following the guide here: https://github.com/ms-iot/windows-iotent-deploy

Comment: Let us take a step back, you indicated that "I've found information that implies IOT Enterprise is binary identical to regular Enterprise", what information was that exactly?

Comment: In the first paragraph here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot-enterprise

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  You can run the same tools on IoT Enterprise that you run on Enterprise.  That does not mean you can enable the same Windows Features, that you enable on IoT Enterprise, on Enterprise.  I am not saying it is not possible but all Windows Features are kept in WinSxS or within the `../sources/sxs` directory within a Windows image.  *Your error is basically telling you, Windows is not aware of which feature you want to use because it does not recognize or find those two features in order to enable them.*

Comment: That clears up a decent amount of my confusion, however I'm currently looking at the WinSxS directory and I've found Embedded-shelllauncher, Is it possible that my vendor sent me the wrong .iso and I need to ask them for an IOT Enterprise iso? (I thought I had asked them for that, but I don't really trust them to be that reliable)

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is merely a different licensing program for Windows 10 Enterprise. As such, your error is not related to that. Did you write the answer file manually or did you use a tool to create it?

Comment: I edited it manually by copying the example xml from the documentation pages. I thought that might have been part of the issue, so I'm working on trying to get the answer file open in WSIM, but while the answer file opens, I can't validate it without a catalog, and I'm having trouble generating a catalog based on my install.wim file. See this other post by me for more info on that: https://superuser.com/questions/1431364/windows-sim-is-failing-to-open-a-wim-with-a-system-badimageformatexception

Comment: So the answer file is for Windows IoT Enterprise or Windows 10 Enterprise.  I figured you were trying to enable IoT Windows Features on Windows 10 Enterprise.